# Support for more devices for ARCore - Huawei Nova Plus

Tags: arcore

Exist the possibility to support more devices? For example, I have a Huawei Nova Plus, I think this phone fit with all the hardware and software capabilities to support applications developed with ARCore.

Answer (score 0):

> Exist the possibility to support more devices?

Yes

But probably only new ones.
Support ARCore is not about how new or old your device is, but if it has gyroscopes, cameras, accelerometers, miniaturized high-resolution displays.

And if it pass for some tests before get launched.

So even maybe new devices will not be support.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instal it manualy if you instal an AR-optional app it will be downloaded automaticly. Click down below to get what i mean:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore

Answer (score 0):

Tbh I guess its possible, the Huawei Nova 2 Plus has a gyroscope, a accelerometer, and a camera, I even contacted google about this, because I wish my phone (a Huawei nova 2 Plus) can run ARcore :)